# What is the difference between != and <>?

Tags: python, syntax, equality, inequality

Perhaps this is a rather newbie-ish question, but I'm curious. I have tried searching for it, but I suppose I lack the correct terminology to search properly.

Difference between `!=` and `<>`.

On searching again, "inequality", I found one that discusses `not ==` and `!=`, but nothing about `<>`.

Comment: You wanted to search for "comparison operators".  So those sigils are all operators, but more specifically they are used for comparison.  Operators are a part of expressions so searching for expressions might have gotten you there too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 2.x, `<>` is equivalent to `!=`, as described in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in):

> The forms <> and != are equivalent; for consistency with C, != is preferred; where != is mentioned below <> is also accepted. The <> spelling is considered obsolescent.

In Python 3.x, `<>` has been removed. Again, the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/whatsnew/3.0.html#removed-syntax) says:

> **Removed Syntax**
>
> ....
>
> Removed <> (use != instead).

Answer (score 9):

They are interchangeable in Python 2, but `<>` [is deprecated](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons) and has been [removed in Python 3](http://docs.python.org/3.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#removed-syntax).

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>>> 1 <> 2
True
>>> 1 != 2
True

Python 3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 16 2013, 00:06:53) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>>> 1 <> 2
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    1 <> 2
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> 1 != 2
True
```

Answer (score 2):

Also if you want to use `<>` in Python 3.X, you can import this from **future** module.

```
Python 3.3.2
>>> from __future__ import barry_as_FLUFL
>>> 1<>1
False
```

Comment: A funny easter egg, but nothing you'd *actually use*.